# Flutter mobile app rendering green problem on specific device - Samsung A12 SM-A125F

Tags: android, flutter, rendering, render

I am developping an app with flutter for both iOS and Android.
I have internal testers for both of the plateforms, and until today I had around 20 testers on Android and 10 on iOS. Nobody had any rendering problem, until today when someone installed the app on there Samsung A12 SM-A125F with version 12 of Android.

Indeed, this user had very unexpected behavior, with every text, container and images in a green color (see pictures).

I really have no idea what to do.

[image: Image 1 with green problem]    and  [image: what it should look like 1] .

[image: Image 2 with green problem]    and [image: what it should look like 2] .

I though maybe it was settings of the phone or something specific of his phone.
So I tried running a Robot Test on Firebase with this model of phone, and I had the surprise to see it did the same thing.

So it is model related I guess.

If someone has an idea where to begin to look for this, I would be really grateful.

Comment: is you other apps installed on device has same issue or only your app has ?

Comment: Only this app has the issue, and it is in closed testers, not published yet

Comment: do you have applied any themedata to MyApp ?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: if you dont mind then can you share apk for the same. have samsung device so can see how it works

Comment: How can I share it? By email?

Comment: you can upload at we transfer and share link here

Comment: Here is the link :
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3496e2fa52caa15f63e3d5d88ecab45d20240322133232/f224c2

Comment: Its looks good. no issue at all. can you uninstall and re install it or possible then restart device too